# It is possible to use a URL address that was used for another project excluded?

Tags: google-app-engine

I used a a URL address on a Google App Engine project that was deleted about a year ago but I need to use the same address again and it is no longer available. There is no way to get get it back? The address doesn't expire after a certain period?

Example:
my-project.appspot.com

Comment: No I don't believe it's possible unless something has changed recently.  would check in the google group you may get a specific response from the appengine support people there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for the `appspot.com` URL, which is based on the project ID, the answer would be **No**, because according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading):

> c. Accept the generated project ID or supply your own ID. *This project
>   ID is used as the App Engine application ID*. **Note that this ID can
>   only be used once: if you subsequently delete your project, you won't
>   be able to re-use the ID in a new project**.